# jdbc insert using batch get number of successfully inserted rows

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, batch-processing

I am trying to get a correct number of inserted rows for any jdbc (using batch and prepared statement).
Now I know 2 ways:

1. `PreparedStatement.getUpdateCount()` - But for batches this method returns 1 for every batch even if every row was rejected.
2. `int[]` as result of `PreparedStatement.executeBatch()` and check every element if it is greater than 0. But for some jdbcs (for example Oracle) this array could contain -2 for every record.

So, is there any way to know the number of successfully inserted rows?

Comment: If you don't get an exception, then every `INSERT` statement was executed successfully, so number of inserted rows equals number of `INSERT` statements in the batch. Update count really makes very little sense for `INSERT` statements. Unless it's an `INSERT from SELECT`, in which case it's really a row count of the `SELECT`.

Comment: My question is directly concerns exceptions.. I know about int[] BatchUpdateException.getUpdateCounts but situation is the same as in PreparedStatement.executeBatch()

Comment: It is normal to me to have some rows rejected by dbms

Comment: If some rows are rejected by DBMS, then you won't get a return value from `executeBatch()`, because it'll throw an exception. In that case, there is no *reason* to examine the results, because every insert succeeded. If your question is about `BatchUpdateException.getUpdateCounts()`, then please edit your question and clarify it.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the batch update count:

Your second option is the way to go but as you have already observed some JDBC drivers do not bother to fully implement this feature.

An update count of `-2 = Statement.SUCCESS_NO_INFO` indicates that the command was processed successfully but that the number of rows affected is unknown.

(And a value of `-3 = Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED` indicates that the command failed to execute successfully and occurs only if a driver continues to process commands after a command fails).

If you only have simple INSERTs you could then reinterpret the -2 as a successful +1 inserted record. (And if the batch update throws an `BatchUpdateException` you would need to evaluate the update counts in the exception instead). Else for other case like `INSERT FROM SELECT` it seems you are out of luck or would need to rely on driver specific APIs.

Comment: `Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED` is actually -3. And I can't reinterpret the -2 as a successful +1 inserted record because -2 returns for every case, even when record was rejected.

Comment: @Limmy corrected the -3. Do you then receive a `BatchUpdateException` when records are rejected? and what JDBC driver does that?

Comment: @Limmy If the JDBC driver returns `SUCCESS_NO_INFO` for a *failed* `INSERT`, then the driver is flawed and needs to be fixed. --- If the JDBC driver returns `EXECUTE_FAILED` as one of the *return* values from `executeBatch()`, then the driver is flawed and needs to be fixed, because that value is only valid for the array returned by `BatchUpdateException.getUpdateCounts()`.